# How can I update the data that comes with SignalR in the scatter graph of the flutter_ecarts library?

Tags: flutter, signalr, refresh, provider, page-refresh

I want to show the graphical part of my web project running with ASP.Net 3.1 as an application in Flutter. For this, I used the flutter_echarts library. I'm capturing the current data from the API with the SignalR library, but I can't update the graph. Can you help me with this? Thank you from now.

Comment: Welcome to SO, see how do I ask a good question [ask], take our [tour], also community need debugging details which means try to post some code you have tried :).